# Apply regular expression for expressjs

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I need to handle requests like this:

```
/key/6435.254.53538
```

I wrote regexp that work in RegexPal

```
(([0-9]+\.?)+)
```

I create handler in Express.js

```
/key/:key(([0-9]+\.?)+)
```

but it returns only last part of the key

```
req.params.key == '53538'
```

how can I retrieve full key?

Comment: well first problem solved, but when I try to extend handler
`/key/:key(([0-9]+\.?)+)/:tab`
and access it with request
`/key/6435.254.53538/sometab`
I will get this unexpected result
`req.params.tab == '53538'`
`req.params[0] == 'sometab'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you accidently capture the digits, and only the last capture is returned. Try either:

```
/key/:key((?:[0-9]+\.?)+)
```

or

```
/key/:key(((?:[0-9]+\.?)+))
```

Alternatively:

```
/key/:key([\d.]+)
```

The only difference is that it allows leading and consecutive periods. If you know that will never be the case, or not a problem, then this regex is a lot easier to read.

Comment: with `(([\d.]+))` its not working - express says `Cannot GET /key/6435.254.53538`